# Azure Benefits Visual Studio with MSDN for custom domains and third party services

Tags: azure, msdn

I have a Azure benefit from my `Visual Studio` with `MSDN subscription`. 
Microsoft doesn't host `MySQL servers` in `Azure`, but I can create a DB from `ClearDB` through the Azure Portal.

**Questions**

- Is this services included in my benefit?
- Can I "Buy" a custom domain with my benefit?

Answer (score 1):

You can provision a `VM` and deploy `MYSQL`, this would be included in your benefit but maybe expensive.

You can provision `SAAS` services like `ClearDB` via `Azure Marketplace` but generally billing is separate. When you provision a third party service there is normally a `FREE TIER` available. If moving to a `PAID TIER` generally this is billed separately from your Azure Payment methods I have found. Point being , depends on the service you are provisioning. Best bet is to ask the service provider sales channel.

Comment: What about the custom domain?
At the end of this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/

Is a screenshoot of GoDaddy License Agreements, so are "custom domains" third party services?

Comment: No , custom domains are part of Azure AD. This is included in your Azure billing profile.

Comment: to be clear:
I do not mean the "old" azure custom domains, wich make only a CNAME or A DNS record for a domain which I buy from GoDaddy (or another service)! Described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

I mean the new "buy a domain" feature, from which I can buy a domain directly from the Azure portal! Described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/

Comment: I see what you mean. All you need to do is setup a new CNAME for example MYAPP.MYDOMAIN.COM and make the value your cloudapp name i.e myapp.cloudapp.net. Its very straightforward. Just make sure your domain name supplier suppports long CNAME values. 1&1 internet DO NOT, GoDaddy do.

Comment: Threre is a misunderstanding!
I do NOT have a own domain! 
I want to buy one throug the Azure portal (see my second link).
My question is: are the domain fees included in my MSDN Azure benefit?

Comment: I believe from MS that the ADD DOMAIN option would be billed via your Azure Subscription payment method whether that be an EA , Invoice model , Pay As You Go (credit card) or capped free allocated amount via eg MSDN subscription. The transaction amount is then paid to the registrar by MS.